# Cannot reboot my pc

Tags: 20.04, shutdown, reboot

Ubuntu 20.04, for a while now I cannot reboot my pc, using the `sudo reboot` I am taken to this screen https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RMP0.jpg

From the GUI I can only shutdown and suspend, while shutdown doesn't even work from the GUI, it just closes all screens and locks up my PC so I have to relog. The only way to shutdown is with `shutdown -h`... Idk what is happening, the shutdown thing isn't a big deal, but the reboot thing is really annoying

Answer (score 0):

From a **normal** terminal session type `shutdown -r now` and enjoy.
(The shutdown command won't work in a limited bash or a grub terminal.)